# how to open another form which will have progress bar while UI thread is busy

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I tried with background worker. When function with loading database data is called, i call backgroundworker too, and i want to open another form which will have progress bar and when loading data is finished, i want to close that form and let user use app normaly. I tried this

```
private void SearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
   //loading data
}
```

this is function which takes long time to execute so i call background worker.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    f.Show();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    f.Close();
}
```

f is my form global varibale , when i write like this, i get error that i cant close form which has been opened in another thread. So what im doing wrong.

Comment: You must use the [Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2) method .

Comment: The form and progress bar are created and shown by the main thread and the background worker is for the actual database loading.

Comment: Only ever write code like that when you know how to do [this kind of debugging](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents-userpreferencechanged/).  Since just about nobody does, nobody should *ever* do this.  Focus on the real problem, never hang the UI thread.  It is never necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You must `Invoke` the method on the thread that owns the control:

```
Invoke(new Action(() => f.Close()));
```

Take a look at [Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.